# Using prisma transaction how can I insert record into second table from the first table record?

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I have two tables: 'accounts' and 'transactions'. I want to use Prisma's $transaction feature to create an account, followed by a transaction that includes the accountId field. The accountId should correspond to the first successful record for the account.

```
 const [accountObj, transaction] = await prisma.$transaction([
  prisma.account.create({
    data: {
      accountCode: Number(accountCode),
      name: name?.trim(),
      type,
      description,
      balance: Number(balance),
      status,
      branchId,
      createdById: req.user.id,
    },
  }),

  ...(Number(balance) > 0
    ? [
        prisma.transaction.create({
          data: {
            type: 'OPENING_BALANCE',
            amount: Number(balance),
            reference: uuidv4(),
            description: `Account opening balance for ${name?.trim()} account created by ${
              req.user.name
            }`,
            status: 'ACTIVE',
            branchId,
            accountId: prisma.account.fields.id,
            createdById: req.user.id,
          },
        }),
      ]
    : []),
])
```

NB. I'm using Prisma v5 so I used like this `accountId: prisma.account.fields.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$transaction` also accepts a callback instead of an array, which allows you to define arbitrary logic within the transaction:

```js
ctx.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
  const data = await tx.account.create({...})
  await tx.transaction.create({
    // something with `data`
  })
})
```

But unless you have some hidden complexity not shown here, you could also do all that in a single query:

```js
prisma.transaction.create({
  data: {
    ...
    account: {
      create: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
})
```

or the other way around

```js
prisma.account.create({
  data: {
    ...
    transaction: {
      create: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
})
```

or creating an account with many transactions

```js
prisma.account.create({
  data: {
    ...
    transaction: {
      createMany: [
        {...},
        {...},
      ]
    }
  }
})
```